# not able to get the value in script tag

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I want to get the `visitor_id` in the script tag.

```html
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    "currentVer": "v137.4",
    "is_internal": false,
    "CBPageType": "Recommendations",
    "is_jdp": false,
    "site_id": "cbnsv",
    "user_status": "Unknown",
    "search_engine": "solr_v4",
    "session_id": "42d3f1b678413a86e8ed79938348d165",
    "server_pool_name": "rails",
    "ipath": "CRJR6",
    "InGlobalExperimentGroups": "LightRegistration:default|extended_top_jobs:experiment1|colab_menu:experiment1|FreeReviewCV:control|HomepageChat:default|RemoveModalExternalApply:experiment1|SourceLocation:default|internal_apply_v3:default",
    "in_global_experiment_groups": "LightRegistration:default|extended_top_jobs:experiment1|colab_menu:experiment1|FreeReviewCV:control|HomepageChat:default|RemoveModalExternalApply:experiment1|SourceLocation:default|internal_apply_v3:default",
    "in_page_experiment_groups": "LightRegistration:default|extended_top_jobs:experiment1|colab_menu:experiment1|FreeReviewCV:control|HomepageChat:default|RemoveModalExternalApply:experiment1|SourceLocation:default|internal_apply_v3:default",
    "browser_id": "X19EF84C01BB9BD92A590AC63F87B5CF5554F72399AB1C3B25092D02C262681753351F7E3AD4D7921B0B0ADDD1833CD50A",
    "visitor_id": "VXDAFEAA801C5A11EC8BCB8F02C62498172220O1",
    "visitor_classification_onet": "",
    "visitor_classification_carotene": "",
    "visitor_state": "Tracked"
  })
</script>
```

The `visitor_id` is dynamic. How can I get the `visitor_id`? I am using selenium. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In whatever javascript executed (not loaded, you can load it before as long as it is executed afterwords) after the `<script>` tag of yours, you just have to do:

```js
var visitorId = window.dataLayer[0].visitor_id;
```

or

```js
var visitorId = window.dataLayer[0]["visitor_id"];
```

I used `0` as the index because your example only pushes one element. But in case is different you will have to use the appropriate index.

**Update**

To evaluate it from java when using selenium use this:

```
WebDriver driver = //your driver declaration here. You should already have this
// ... random selenium stuff you sure have
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String visitorId = (String) js.executeScript("window.dataLayer[0].visitor_id");
```

Comment: how can i do in selenium i am using java and I think you use js script

Comment: hi, I use that but it throws a null value in the console...

Comment: What does `js.executeScript("window.dataLayer.length")` return?

Comment: same null value is coming in console

Comment: I resolved it.. Thanks